# UFT 12.01 recognizes files when run from one machine but not from another

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am running UFT 12.01 from two Windows 7 machines. On one of them, when I try to reference file objects on a remote drive, I have no problem, but on the other I get errors like:

> The DataTable.Import (file) operation failed. Invalid file.

or

> "File Not Found".

I can view the files on either machine. I couldn't find anything under **Settings** or **Options** in UFT, but maybe I'm just not looking in the right place.

I'd appreciate any suggestions for resolving this. Thanks!

Comment: It would be cool to see what file name the two machines use in their `DataTable.Import` call. Are they the equal? Do both machines have the same drive letter mapping? Or are you using UNCs?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar issue when referencing fully qualified UNC paths to files held on remote servers.  I found that adding a network mapping to the location on each PC meant that the file could be found on the offending machines.

I still used the UNC path in my scripts, but having the network mapping in place  allowed the execution PC to locate the file being loaded.